# In Ubuntu 12.04, how can I fix application icons to the panel? and a question about tomboy

Tags: panel, tomboy

Sometimes, I really like to put quick launch apps in the panel like VLC Player to play my music just by one click. Sometimes, I like to keep tomboy in the panel to be in hand. But I don't know how to do that !

Another point. In Windows 7, there is a small application called sticky notes I'm sure you guys know. The most important feature that it can be stuck to the desktop holding important things to remember. Does tomboy do such a thing, or there is another app ?!

Thank you !

Comment: Please split this up into different questions, this site works best when there's one question per issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you're using your favorite application, its icon will be showing in the quick launch panel. All you've to do is `right click` on it and select `lock to launcher`.

Check this link for a suitable sticky note [Click me](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-little-useful-sticky-notes-app-for-linux/)